# What is the use of Main File in Symfony 2 Bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

What is the use of Main File in Symfony 2 Bundle?

Below is the Default Path of a file:

Project->src->BundleName->BundleName.php

For Ex:

Symfony_Project/src/AppBundle/AppBundle.php

The Content Of Above file is Always Blank:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

1. What is the use of this file in symfony?
2. Why We Can use this File?
3. Is it Mandatory or Not? /Can we Delete it?
4. Why it is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file can be used to override any other bundle (your application bundles / third party bundles) and its resources. You can set parent bundle for a given bundle. For example, you are having FosUserBundle included and you want to override some of its actions/layout files etc.. To accomplish this, create you bundle UserBundle.php. add FosUserBundle as its parent like as follows :

```
// src/UserBundle/UserBundle.php
namespace UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class UserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

Override controller:

```
// src/UserBundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php
namespace UserBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;

class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
    public function registerAction()
    {
        $response = parent::registerAction();

        // ... do custom stuff
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Then within your UserBundle directory structure, you can override controllers/layout files etc..

For more info please refer this link : https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/bundles/inheritance.html